# Passive voice vs. using "I" in a sole-author paper

Tags: writing

I am a fan of using "we" in co-authored papers in order to avoid using passive voice. However, I tend to see passive voice, rather than active voice with "I," in single-author papers. Furthermore, I have read numerous suggestions to avoid using the first-person "I" in a research paper.

Isn't it appropriate to use "I" and active voice?

Comment: Thanks @ff524. I still think this question can stand alone because it is specifically addressing single-author papers, whereas the other question doesn't address this directly at all, either in the question or responses.

Comment: OK, I changed the duplicate to one asking specifically about single-author papers. Note that the question doesn't specifically ask about third person vs first person, but the answers (particularly [the one by Henry](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/2947/11365)) address this.

Comment: (Also see: [Using first person or third person in papers?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11659/using-first-person-or-third-person-in-papers))