# Research Paper Self Referrel

Tags: writing

How would I refer to myself in a research paper? I know the use of 'I' is out of the question, so would it be 'this researcher'?

Comment: I personally use "we" for single-author papers, but have had reviewers point out I should use "I". In which cases I made an exception just for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choice of personal pronoun in single-author papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2945/choice-of-personal-pronoun-in-single-author-papers) and many others

Comment: The use of "I" had better not be out of the question; I've used it.

Answer (score 2):

This is very field-dependent. In my field (engineering), it is typical for authors to use "we" even if there is only one author. (FWIW, I don't really like that convention, but it's what most authors do.) In other fields, such as in the humanities, it's usual for a single-authored paper to use "I". (It's not out of the question.) I've also seen "the author" or "the researcher" or phrases like that.